# Method returns TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, openweathermap

I am using openweathermap to grab weather data which returns a JSON object like this:

```
blank = {
    "coord": {"lon": -92.11, "lat": 46.78},
    "weather": [
        {"id": 800, "main": "Unknown", "description": "Unknown", "icon": "01d"}
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 0,
        "feels_like": 0,
        "temp_min": 0,
        "temp_max": 0,
        "pressure": 0,
        "humidity": 0,
    },
    "visibility": 0,
    "wind": {"speed": 0, "deg": 0},
    "clouds": {"all": 1},
    "dt": 0,
    "sys": {"type": 1, "id": 3903, "country": "US", "sunrise": 0, "sunset": 0},
    "timezone": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Unknown",
    "cod": 0,
}
```

I am having an issue returning a string on `["weather"]["description"]` This will throw a type error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Method:

```
class OpenWeather:
    def descrip(self):
        return self.data["weather"]["description"]
```

Would anyone have any tips?

Comment: What kind of thing is `self.data["weather"]`?

Comment: Right now, 'weather' is a list with one element, which is a dictionary. I'd suggest removing the square brackets, thus making 'weather' itself a dictionary, unless you need to keep it that way, in which case Jan's answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
class OpenWeather:
    def descrip(self):
        return self.data["weather"][0]["description"]
        #                          ^^^
```

Or some sort of list comprehension as `weather` is a list (possibly a list of dictionaries, but your example only includes one dictionary).